# Ruby On Rails database connection

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm just learning RoR and am trying to set up a database to connect to. I think the problem is something with file paths. When I type "rake db:schema:dump --trace" I get:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/cannoncollins/Sites/simple_cms/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/cannoncollins/Sites/simple_cms/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Users/cannoncollins/Sites/simple_cms/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/cannoncollins/.rbenv/versions/2.2.1/bin/rake:33:in `<main>'
```

Here's my database.yml:

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: ****
  password: ****
  host: localhost

development:
  <<: *default
  database: simple_cms_development
```

Gem List:

```
*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bigdecimal (1.2.6)
io-console (0.4.3)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (5.4.3)
mysql2 (0.3.18)
power_assert (0.2.2)
psych (2.0.8)
rake (10.4.2)
rdoc (4.2.0)
test-unit (3.0.8)
```

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: I hope your `yml` is not really all on one line like that.  YAML is line/space sensitive, this would not work.  If it is not like this, please fix your OP to reflect.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of Ruby installed?

Comment: No, my yml isn't. I think it just pasted weird. I'm pretty sure I only have the one version of Ruby installed. But if you saw the other comment to the answer, it's now giving me a different error after I updated bundler

Answer (score 0):

> rake aborted! LoadError: cannot load such file -- bundler/setup

A typical reason for this issue is that you don't have bundler installed. Try installing bundler and then run your rake command again.

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
rake db:schema:dump --trace
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I did that and now i'm on a different issue, says "Could not find i18n-0.7.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems." However when i run bundle is shows "Using i18n 0.7.0

Answer (score 0):

In your database.yml file, add socket as follows-

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: ****
  password: ****
  host: localhost
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```